# Code to Get rid of Match Case

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a problem in my code.

While searching, it only search the lower case values. However i want it search whether the value is capital or small or mix.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim intValueToFind As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

intValueToFind = Me.TextBox3.Value
For Each rng In rng    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values
    If LCase(rng.Value) = intValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Found value on row " & rng.Value)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next rng

' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")

End Sub
```

Kindly review and advise how can i get the solution what i need...

Thanks
Salman

Comment: I suggest replacing `intValueToFind = Me.TextBox3.Value` by `intValueToFind = LCase(Me.TextBox3.Value)` so both sides of the comparison have been changed to lower case
`

Comment: Thanks Tony it really worked...